# Invalid JSON Response MVC API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api

I have one JSON Request as below :

```
{
  "Products": [
      {
         "ProductId": 1,
         "Barcode": "sample string 2",
         "ProductExtId": "sample string 3",
         "CategoryName": "sample string 4",
         "BrandName": "sample string 5",
         "StyleName": "sample string 6",
         "ProductName": "sample string 7",
         "Properies": [
              {
                  "PropertyKey": "sample string 1",
                  "PropertyValue": "sample string 2"
             },
             {
                  "PropertyKey": "sample string 1",
                  "PropertyValue": "sample string 2"
            }
               ]
        }
     ]
  }
```

As per above JSON Request my Class AS BELOW :

```
 public class Propery
{
    public string PropertyKey { get; set; }
    public string PropertyValue { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
    public string ProductExtId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string BrandName { get; set; }
    public string StyleName { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public List<Propery> Properies { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject 
{
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    //public Product Products { get; set; }
}
```

**My DataController :**

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ResponseType(typeof(List<productGetData_Result>))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetProductData()
    {
        List<Product> prodata = new List<Product>();

        var list = db.productGetData().ToList();

        foreach (var listdata in list)
        {
            Product pdata = new Product();

            pdata.Barcode = listdata.StockNo;
            pdata.ProductExtId = "";
            pdata.CategoryName = listdata.Class2Descr;
            pdata.BrandName = listdata.Class1Descr;
            pdata.StyleName = listdata.SubClass1Cd;
            pdata.ProductName = listdata.AnalCode2;
            pdata.ProductSubTitle = listdata.AnalCode2;
            pdata.ProductImage = listdata.ImageID;
            pdata.Color = listdata.SubClass2Cd;
            pdata.ColorImage = "";
            pdata.FabricName = "";
            pdata.SeasonName = listdata.AnalCode3;
            pdata.GroupName = listdata.Class2Descr;
            pdata.SearchKeywords = listdata.ItemDesc;
            pdata.MRP = Convert.ToInt16(listdata.Retail_Price);
            pdata.BuyingPrice = Convert.ToInt16(listdata.CurrentCost);
            pdata.StockQty = Convert.ToInt16(listdata.StockQty);
            pdata.AllowedQty = Convert.ToInt16(listdata.StockQty);
            pdata.ProductFor = "";
            pdata.AgeType = "";
            pdata.AgeFrom = 1;
            pdata.AgeTo = 2;
            pdata.Age = "";
            pdata.KeyFeatures = "";
            pdata.Description = listdata.ItemDesc;
            pdata.Condition = "";
            pdata.Disclaimer = "";
            pdata.IsGiftAvailable = true;
            pdata.IsPopular = true;
            pdata.IsNewArrival = true;
            pdata.IsSponsored = true;
            pdata.IsShippingAvailable = true;
            pdata.CompanyName = "Siddharth Creation";
            pdata.ProductAgeDate = Convert.ToDateTime(listdata.Dateinsert);
            pdata.IsActive = true;
            pdata.IntegrationFor = "Siddharth Creation";

            prodata.Add(pdata);
        }

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //HttpRequestMessage requestmsg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://retailerintegration.zoomi.in");
            //requestmsg.Headers.Add("token", "");
            string stringData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(prodata);
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("");
            MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue contentType =new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
            var contentData = new StringContent(stringData, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("/api/Product/ProductSave", contentData).Result;
            var Message = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }

        return Ok(prodata);
    }
```

AS per above class and DataController, i am returning below JSON Response :

```
[
{
    "ProductId": 0,
    "Barcode": "170604658",
    "ProductExtId": "",
    "CategoryName": "MENS SHIRTS",
    "BrandName": "KRISS",
    "StyleName": "PRN",
    "ProductName": "FORMAL WEAR",
    "Properies": null
},
{
    "ProductId": 0,
    "Barcode": "170604657",
    "ProductExtId": "",
    "CategoryName": "MENS SHIRTS",
    "BrandName": "KRISS",
    "StyleName": "PRN",
    "ProductName": "FORMAL WEAR",
    "Properies": null
}
]
```

currently i am returning product class & its items as per above.

So, now how to pass root object in datacontroller to get the JSON Response as per JSON Request.

Comment: You would need to initialize a new `RootObject` and set its `Products` property to your current collection - e.g `RootObject model = new RootObject() { Products = prodata };` and then serialize that, (not `prodata`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now i m getting as per JSON Request.

Comment: How to add values in Properies array.

Comment: That's a different question, so ask a new question (and I see you have been given a correct answer to this one already). Hint: `pdata.Properies = new List<Propery>(){ new Propery(){ PropertyKey = "sample string 1", PropertyValue = "sample string 2" } };`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Your given hint is working for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
 List<Product> prodata = new List<Product>();
       RootObject _rootObject = new RootObject();
        var list = db.productGetData().ToList();

        foreach (var listdata in list)
        {
           var _listOfProperties = new List<Property>();
           //if product list contains data of properties
           foreach(var _prop in listdata.Properies)
           {
              var property = new Property();
              property.PropertyKey = _prop.PropertyKey;
              property.PropertyValue = _prop.PropertyValue;
              _listOfProperties.Add(property);
           }

            Product pdata = new Product();
            pdata.Properties = _listOfProperties;
            prodata.Add(pdata);
        }
_rootObject.Products = prodata;

and now serialize it

string stringData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_rootObject);
```

Comment: How to add values in Properies array.

Comment: @YogeshSharma check the answer now, I have assumed that product list contains the values of properties.